# Inline delete confirmation in datatable desktop

Tags: data-tables

I want to manage the Duplicate and remove lines in a datatable without using a modal dialog or a pop up overlay.

Have you some examples of how to manage these actions within the same datatable?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a bit more detail? What do you mean you want to 'manage' them? And why is a modal not an option?

Comment: When you say 'Remove': are you referring to a deletion of an instance, or just removal of an item from a collection? In other words, is it a true destructive action, or just removing an association?

Comment: I meant say how to display delete/duplicate within a datatable. I avoid a modal because I don't wanted block the visibility of other sections. @Mike M Also these actions are not destructive, We only create or remove an association.

Answer (score 1):

I applied delete/duplicate actions as follows[image]